# What'sApp installed on anbox on ubuntu 17.10 doesn't work – probably it can't acces the internet

Tags: 17.10, adb, anbox, whatsapp

I installed anbox with whatsapp on my ubuntu computer just as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944238/anbox-install-problem/944245#944245).

I started whatsapp an typed in my phone number. By the way, my phone is no smartphone and that's why I need whatsapp on anbox.

I get this error message all time: `Unable to connect. Please check that you are connected to the Internet and try again. Please reboot your phone if the problem persists.` (Please note the image below.) I rebooted my computer multiple times.

[whatsapp error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl61I.png)

I think it's about anbox can't acces to internet. For example, I get this error when I try to use the WebViewer browser tester: `Webpage not available. The webpage at http://google.com/ could not be loaded because: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` Same for any other website. Similar happens when I try to set up an email account.

Fly mode is turned off. The settings tell me it as both IP and Mac Adress.

What did I do wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have WhatsApp installed on your phone in order to use it on the desktop as it connects to your phone to access the service. The reason it cannot connect is because you do not have the app installed on your phone.

Comment: Where does the app knows from on what kind of device it runs? And: the text says it will write an sms with the activating code to my mobile phone. What for needs the app to be installed on a phone? The app shouldn't even know.

Comment: @Asqiir That's an interesting question. The app knows about it in web browsers from the [user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox), however the user agent can be switched by the user of the web browser from Ubuntu desktop to Android phone, so the app might be fooled that it was connecting to an Android phone instead of to a web browser running on an Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: WhatsApp Web works like this `server <-----> phone <-----> web` this is because it uses your phone as a proxy. Your phone simply forwards messages to your web client

Comment: @Tom I'm not trying to user WhatsApp Web – I know the app has to be installed to make this work. I am trying to run the app directly on anbox.

Answer (score 1):

It is Anbox not connected to the internet. Try opening the Anbox browser, it won't connect either. On the Anbox website it is stated that network functionality is not fully developed.

There is a discussion here:
https://discourse.anbox.io/t/no-network-connectivity/152/5