# How can I prevent Anbox apps from accessing my files?

Tags: permissions, security, anbox

Here [Anbox install problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944238/anbox-install-problem)
@karel said:

> WhatsApp also asks if you want to give the app permission to access the files on your device which is another security risk in my opinion. I think it's OK to give WhatsApp permission to access the files on my phone, but I don't want to give the app permission to access the files on my computer. Permissions are a matter of fundamental importance in Linux. You should be very careful about giving permissions to an application that it doesn't already have by default, and the telegram-latest snap package in Ubuntu 16.04 has better support than WhatsApp including Telegram Calls voice calls which are currently available to users around the world.

I'm wondering, is there a way to make absolute sure that apps installed in Anbox cannot gain access to files on the computer? 
Maybe running Anbox in Firejail can prevent this?

Comment: @user535733 what do you exactly mean by "other disabling features" What can i do more beside using of firejail?

Comment: @Zanna fairly said. My previous comments cheerfully withdrawn.