# How to run android apps in my pc

Tags: ubuntu-for-android, android-emulator

Someone knows how can I use android apps in my pc using software from the Ubuntu archive ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [shashlik](http://www.shashlik.io/) or [anbox](https://anbox.io/) to run Android apps natively on Linux. anbox is more preferable over shashlik. Also, you can use [android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) in virtual box. GenyMotion and android emulator provided by Google for android development are also good choise.

for shashlik also see [how to install and-run android apk on linux with shashlik](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-run-android-apk-on-linux-with-shashlik/)

Answer (score 1):

Anbox is a great piece of software for standalone apps on you're Ubuntu system. It still has a few bugs in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but is pretty good other than that!
Check it out [here](https://anbox.io/).

**CORRECTION**: The *bugs* I mentioned are better described as errors. The devs haven't added support for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS yet.

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944238/anbox-install-problem/944245#944245).

Comment: Oh, right. I'll change that.