# Alexa for Ubuntu

Tags: amazon

I received an Amazon Echo device as a gift. It included instructions for activating and installing Alexa, but only for Windows and Mac.

A query to the Amazon help line returned a brief reply that Linux was not supported.

Has anyone tried (successfully) to install Alexa on this device?

Comment: How about https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/wiki/Ubuntu-Linux-Quick-Start-Guide ?

Comment: "install Alexa on this device" - I don't understand? What would you have to install on your computer in order to use Alexa on your Echo?

Answer (score 7):

I think this poster means to  install the **AMAZON ALEXA Hub** application suite or equivalent controlling software that is available for MAC, WINDOWS & Android platforms on the  Ubuntu system,p robably with Indicator & Notification support included as well.

### 0. SOLUTION ZERO

Install the Amazon Alexa App on your Android phone / Apple handset and keep your eyes peeled for projects on Linux to surface for proposed Ubuntu Integration.

### 1.  SOLUTION ONE

Go to the Snapcraft Snapd Store - 
https://snapcraft.io/anbox-installer .

Copy and paste the following into your terminal and install [Anbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944238/anbox-install-problem/944245#944245):

```
sudo snap install anbox-installer --classic
```

OR

```
sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```

Enter your password, this will install the Android version on your Ubuntu system, then you are good to go!

More instruction on :
https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/docs/install.md

### 2. SOLUTION  TWO

Install WINE ( again add it as a Snap or look in the Software Center for availability ) to get the Windows version to work and run it from there . 
May give you different functionality to the Android version .

### 3. SOLUTION THREE

Do it Yourself
http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Echo_Compatible_Linux_Device_Anderson.pdf

### 4. SOLUTION FOUR

Install Chrome and use their Assistant through their Web Browser and your webcam then return the Alexa unit back for a refund. 
 Rinse and repeat the same question but for Google HOME !!!

---

> Results may vary.
>
> Thank me if one of these solutions WORKS :P

Comment: So much guessing and effort and not even sure ? You made me laugh tho..

Comment: BTW I like you to change Solution ZERO :)

Comment: What about installing windows in virtual box? Will Alexa work on it?