# Echo Show 8 needs Alexa App

Tags: android

Tried to use the info here:
Alexa for Ubuntu
[Alexa for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060141/alexa-for-ubuntu)

... did the "sudo snap install anbox-installer --classic" thing, and it did its thing... but still no ANBOX... yet I get this:

snap "anbox-installer" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

next did: $ sudo apt install adb... which installed fine w/o error,

but when I do this:
$ adb install /home/cf73/Downloads/alexa.apk,

I get:
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
error: no devices/emulators found
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found
- waiting for device -
^C (ie abort as it just hangs...)

------------------------------------- next rabbit hole:

So, went to:https://linuxhint.com/install_anbox_android_emulator_ubuntu/
...and followed it's version to get this darn AnBox:

which after doing all its info I get to try again using: sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox

but got: 'error: snap "anbox" is not available on beta for this architecture (i386) but exists on other architectures (amd64).'

BUT ---- seems that's as far as I can get!

I ALSO run into this vicious circle trying to get the darn Alexa APP at:
Amazon Alexa: Appstore for Android
[https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-com-Amazon-Alexa/dp/B00P03D4D2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00P03D4D2)

I click on "Download the Amazon App" which takes me to this:
Getting Started with Apps...
https://www.amazon.com/androidapp

BUT, that link just goes back to:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1002999431
which wants me to go back to:
https://www.amazon.com/androidapp

Apparently I need this bloody APP thing to finish setting up my Echo Show 8, requiring this phone APP, but I have no phone - smart or otherwise (I use HAM Radio for communications... or someone can email me..)

Comment: I downloaded "alexa.apk", but launching it gets:
The file '/home/cf73/Downloads/alexa.apk' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit.
...then making it executable via permissions, and click on it, but nothing happens....

Comment: After looking into this a bit more - I installed Virtual Box, then downloaded an Android 9 ISO to install on it, so I can install this APK APP thing to finish setting up my Echo Show 8... BUT - during trying to install Android, I got cold feet, panicked, almost threw up, etc. with all the install things about creating partition, creating a GRUB, etc. that I aborted it all and decided to await until I could get more confidence that I wasn't fixing to crash everything :-\

I should've just gotten a car battery with my money instead of this darn Alexa monstrosity!   I'm outta here...

Comment: any alternatives to AnBox that run android apps on 32-bit?

Comment: any alternatives to AnBox that run android apps on 64-bit Vista?
(I'm sinking deeper into the rabbit hole)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returned the echo show 8 to amazon for full refund because it was misleading in its advertisement - never said it had to have the alexa app to finish setting it up, and never said the app requires 64-bit linux or windows 10, an android device, etc. none of which I had.